# Is it possible to delete a chat room?

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, chat

I move some comments made by @TomWijsman and me to a chat room and since we stop to talk I think will be good to delete that room.

How can I delete a chat room I opened?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Deleting chat rooms is possible, but only for moderators. In cases were you feel strongly, ask a moderator do delete it; however for cases where you just think "this doesn't matter anymore", just leave it be. There's still the issue of community moderation; if people abuse the chat in any way, but are quick enough to delete their room, nobody will ever know. All chat activity is intentionally public (except for behind-the-scense moderator chats of course).

And inactive rooms will be removed after a while anyway (either frozen or deleted; see [the corresponding FAQ entry](http://chat.stackexchange.com/faq#retention) for the precise rules).

Comment: I'm mod but can't find the way to delete. And it's curently frozen. ;)

Comment: Oops, sorry, I missed your diamond. You should see a delete link in the "room" menu when you're inside the room, and a delete button on the "access" tab of the room info page.

Comment: Sorry. Really can't find [here](http://img254.imageshack.us/img254/7238/chat1db.jpg) or [here](http://img804.imageshack.us/img804/8664/chat2p.jpg). But since you said it will be freeze and after deleted I think I will leave it in that way. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that is possible.  Why do you want to delete it? Just to clean up a bit? I am pretty sure that the room will eventually go "inactive" and won't show in the default list.

Comment: I want to delete because it was a sequence of comments in a post. Then I moved to chat when the system ask to do it. Know we don't need the chat anymore.